# I don't understand why this SQL statement doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm writting a page in asp.net for a schedule. I'm using template fields to be able to update a `GridView` and save the information entered to a access database. for some reason, when I run the update command, it doesn't update the database correctly. Let me know if you see anything.

Code for the `RowUpdating` event:

```
protected void table1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //get the value in the fullname textbox and assign it t a string varible
    TextBox txtFull = (TextBox)(table1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtfullname"));
    string FullName = txtFull.Text;
    //split the fullname string and assign the first and last name to new string variables
    //accordingly
    string[] splitstring = FullName.Split(' ');
    string firstName = splitstring[0];
    string lastName = splitstring[1];

    //assign the first and last name to the appropriate updateparameters
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["FirstName"].DefaultValue = firstName;
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["LastName"].DefaultValue = lastName;
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["FullName"].DefaultValue = FullName;

    //concantenate the username of the user's schedule you are editing.
    string username = firstName + "." + lastName;

    //instantiate an array with all the names of the updateparameters
    string[] dayArray = new string[] { "sun1","mon1","tues1","wed1","thurs1"
        ,"fri1","sat1","sun2","mon2","tues2","wed2","thurs2","fri2","sat2"};

    //loop through the controls and assign the text value of the textboxes to
    //the sqlUpdateParameters
    for (int i = 0; i < table1.Columns.Count - 4; i++)
    {
        TextBox day = (TextBox)(table1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt" + dayArray[i]));
        string strDay = day.Text;
        SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters[i].DefaultValue = strDay;
    }

    string totHours = calcHours(sender, e).ToString();

    //assign the calculated total amount of hours to the totHours UpdateParameter
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["totHours"].DefaultValue = totHours;

    //set the update statement for the SqlDataSource to update the database with the 
    //information pulled from the form

    if (Convert.ToDouble(totHours) > 0)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Employee SET FullName = @FullName," +
            "FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName, Sunday1 = @sun1, Monday1 = @mon1," +
            "Tuesday1 = @tues1, Wednesday1 = @wed1, Thursday1 = @thurs1, Friday1 = @fri1," +
            "Saturday1 = @sat1, Sunday2 = @sun2, Monday2 = @mon2, Tuesday2 = @tues2," +
            "Wednesday2 = @wed2, Thursday2 = @thurs2, Friday2 = @fri2, Saturday2 = @sat2," +
            "TotalHoursWorked = @totHours WHERE UserName = '" + username + "'";

        //run the update statement
        SqlDataSource1.Update();
    }
    //rebind the data in accordance with the admin

    BindData();
}
```

Here is a before and after of what it looks like in the browser

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

The order of the update parameters start from the first sunday and the last 4 do not want to be changed in the loop hence the `"table1.Columns.Count - 4"`.

Code for the BindData event

```
protected void BindData()
{
    //get the username from the cookies collection and assign it to a string varialbe
    string username = Request.Cookies["username"].Value;
    string HouseID = Request.Cookies["houseID"].Value;
    //make the sql select parameter equal to the username of the user that is logged in
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["username"].DefaultValue = username;
    //check to if the user logged in is a admin. if it is then display everthing associated
    //with the houssID depending on which button was pressed, otherwise 
    //display the schedule associated with the user that is logged in.
    if (username == "admin")
    {
        if (HouseID == "5")
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Employee";
        }
        else
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE houseID = '" + HouseID + "'";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE UserName = '" + username + "'";
        table1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    }
    //rebind the sqldatasource to the gridview to display the schedule correctly
    table1.DataBind();
}
```

Let me know if anything else is needed and I will provide it.

`calc hours` returns `-1000` if something goes wrong in that method. That's why it checks to see if `totHours > 0`

Comment: Note that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation.

Comment: I understand that Michael. It's not even close to being done yet and regardless the database doesn't hold any sensitive data. only holds first and last names and such.

Comment: Injection attacks aren't only about stealing sensitive information.  It's more about typing in a last name of "smith';--delete users" and ruining your database.

Comment: You're indexing your SQL parameters and table columns by number. Are you sure they are in the same order? Probably not since this is the result. It would be better to index by name.

Comment: yes they are in the same order. starts on the first sunday at position 0 goes to the second saturday.

Comment: Instea `SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters[i].DefaultValue = strDay` try ` SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters[dayArray[i]].DefaultValue = strDay` and move `if (Convert.ToDouble(totHours) > 0)...` before `for` statement.

Comment: I just decided to use string variables inside my sql statement instead of trying to use update parameters.